# Passing more than 2 values from JavaScript to an Apex controller

Tags: visualforce

I have a script where I have two value. a and b.

```
   <script>
      var a= 1; 
      var b=2; 
   </script>
```

I want to pass this value to my controller which have a method.

```
 public class mycontroller {

     public void myvalues(string a1, string b1){
         system.debug(a1 + ' '+ b1);
     }

 }
```

Haw can I achieve this. Please help me with the best way to get the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `apex:actionFunction` paired with `apex:param`.  https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm

VF Page:

```
<script>
  var a = 1;
  var b = 2;
  doWork(a, b);
</script>

<apex:actionFunction action="{!mywork}" name="doWork" rerender="something">
  <apex:param name="firstParam" assignTo="{!aVar}" value="" />
  <apex:param name="firstParam" assignTo="{!bVar}" value="" />
</apex:actionFunction>
```

Controller:

```
public class MyController
{
  public String aVar{get; set;}
  public String bVar{get; set;}

  public PageReference myWork()
  {
    //aVar and bVar should both already be assigned here
    System.debug('avar = ' + aVar);
    return null;
  }
}
```